# Did Voltaire say/write "Everything you say should be true, but not everything true should be said."?

Tags: history, quotes

There is a popular saying:

> Everything you say should be true, but not everything true should be
> said.

On the internet, many pages attribute this quote to Voltaire - however, I could not find any source. **Did Voltaire really say or write this?**

---

Note: I did find two related quotes:

> There are truths which are not for all men, nor for all times.

*Voltaire, Letter to François-Joachim de Pierre, cardinal de Bernis (23 April 1764)*

> [...] und wenn alles, was man sagt, wahr sein muß, so
> ist darum nicht auch Pflicht, alle Wahrheit öffentlich zu
> sagen.".

My translation:

> [...] and if everything one says must be true, this does not mean it is a duty to make all truth public.

*Immanuel Kant, nachlass*

Maybe one of these morphed into the one I am asking about?

Comment: @Evargalo: Cool. Sounds like an answer, consider making one :-).

Comment: How is your translation not effectively the sought aphorism?

Comment: @philipxy: Yes, it is *effectively* the same aphorism, but not *literally*. I was looking for a direct quote from Voltaire. Anyway, Evargalo's answer basically says the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Partial answer*

**Not found in French**

Looking for Voltaire's citations in French with related words ("*vérité*", "*vrai*") on [various](https://citation-celebre.leparisien.fr/auteur/voltaire?theme=verite) [websites](https://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Voltaire) doesn't bring any hit that could be the source of the quote in English.

Proving a negative is difficult [*citation needed*] but this hints towards *no*.

**Alexis Piron**

The second part of the sentence,

> "not everything true should be said"

became a proverb in French:

> "Toute vérité n'est pas bonne à dire"

It is first [referenced](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/toute_v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9_n%E2%80%99est_pas_bonne_%C3%A0_dire) in 1725 in a comical opera by [Alexis Piron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexis_Piron), another dramatist from the early 18th century, who was not in good terms with Voltaire.

Speculation : It is quite possible that popular culture and internet switched the attribution from little-known Piron to famous Voltaire along the years.

However, the context doesn't look at all like the first part of the sentence you're quoting (*Everything you say should be true*) :

> Si d'aventure , votre Époux
> Vous juroit qu'il n'est pas jaloux ,
> Et du passé vouloit s'instruire,
> Jeunes Épouses , taisez-vous.
> Toute vérité n'est pas bonne à dire.

Proposed translation :

> If ever your husband
> Swears to you he isn't jealous,
> And from the past wants to learn,
> Young Wives, keep silent.
> Not every truth is good to say.

Your version sounds much more philosophical than this *boulevard*.